# how to isolate js script from the html code?

Tags: javascript, html

i'd like to isolate the javascript code from the html code in two diferent files, originally I had this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="body">HTML Text</p>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#body").text("JS Text");
         });
</script>
```

and the output of the <-p-> was the expected "JS Text".

Then I tried to isolate the js script to another file (**script.js**):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var text = document.getElementById('body');
    text.innerHTML ='JS Text';
}
```

I've also make the reference  at the html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="scripts.js"></script>
```

but then the output text is no longer the expected (JS Text) but (HTML text)

what else do I need to make the js script work again?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: You want to be sure that the document is loaded, not the window.

Comment: Also, where are you loading jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is invalid to place anything after the closing HTML tag, so while your first bit of code worked, it was invalid.

If you remove the JavaScript and place it in its own file, it will continue to work as long as you reference the file properly (use a relative reference and test the file on a web server) and place the `script` element just prior to the closing `body` tag so that when the script is processed and attempts to find the right DOM element, the DOM will have been loaded at that time.

**FYI:**

- If you have JQuery in the referenced `script` file, then your
  `script` that references JQuery will need to occur in the HTML prior
  to the `script` that uses it.
- The `type` attribute in the `script` tag has not been needed in
  several years.
- It's not a good idea to name anything `body` so that you won't cause
  confusion with the `body` element.
- Don't use `.innerHTML` when the string you are working with doesn't
  contain any HTML. `.innerHTML` has security and performance
  implications. Use `.textContent` instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="body">HTML Text</p>
        <script src="relativePathToFile.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @D_N Everything one needs to know about how to do this correctly is addressed in the answer. You don't need to write a novel to answer a simple question.